# Transform: scale() not transforming from center

Tags: css, scale, css-transforms

When I hover, it scales perfectly but the logo moves up a little bit. I tried transform-origin: center (even though that is the default) and nothing changed.

HTML

```
<div class="portfolio-projects">
    <div class="project">
        <img src="#" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
portfolio-projects {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 50px;
    margin: 50px 0;
    max-width: 1050px;

.project {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: $gray;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 325px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-35%) scale(.8);
    transition: .2s;
}

.project:hover {
    img {
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(.9);
    }
}
```

Comment: `transform: translate();` doesn't calculate from the *container* of the element it is placed in, but from the element *itself*. So if you use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` it will shift the element halft its height up and half its width to the inline-start (left, if not `rtl`)

Answer (score 0):

Wow. So I just needed to change it to this

```
.project:hover {
    img {
        transform: translate(-50%,-35%) scale(.9);
    }
}
```

I forgot to adjust the hover after adjust the original value.